# How to get n elements of list in Jpa repository?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Can I get findTop4ByOrderByIdDescInvesteeId(Long investeeId)?

List findTop4ByOrderByIdDescInvesteeId(Long investeeId); this is not working

Answer (score 0):

your syntaxis is wrong, orderByDesc should be at the very end.

and there should be a parameter after first By

try `findTop4ByIdOrderByIdDesc`